# How to remove items from ItemsCollection where Tag is something?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I want to remove all items that have `Tag` set to string `Dynamic`:

```
foreach (MenuItem item in Items.Cast<object>().Where(mi => mi is MenuItem && ((MenuItem) mi).Tag == "Dynamic"))
{
    Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Unfortunately, it won't allow me to remove items while iterating the collection.

Is there a simple way to remove all items that have a certain condition met true, in this case `Tag` set to a string `Dynamic`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you cannot change a collection while iterating it, you will have to store the result items and remove it in a second step.

```
IList<MenuItem> itemsToRemove = Items.Cast<object>().Where(mi => mi is MenuItem && ((MenuItem) mi).Tag == "Dynamic").ToList();
foreach (MenuItem item in itemsToRemove)
{
    Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: "Collection was modified, enumeration operation may not execute."

Comment: Edited the post. Using ToList() generates a new instance of the items to remove. It will work now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method [`List<T>.RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) instead, like this:

```
Items.Cast<object>()
    .RemoveAll(mi => mi is MenuItem && ((MenuItem) mi).Tag == "Dynamic");
```

Comment: Is guess 'RemoveAll' is an external extension method? It sounds interesting.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal How do I use this method? It says it can't find it, even though I added `using System.Collections.Generic`.

Comment: @rFactor I was wondering, too. The extension method RemoveAll exists just for the List<T> class, maybe you're using another collection.

Comment: @rFactor, `items` in your code should be of type `List<T>`, so that you can use the method `RemoveAll()`

Comment: I'm using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.aspx.

Comment: @rFactor, Use [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) method to convert it to be of type `List<T>` something like `Items.ToList<MenuItem>().RemoveAll()`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal wouldn't that will just delete the items from the List created by calling ToList() and leave the original collection unchanged?